# Bought a flight ticket with virtual card issuer Privacy.com. Hours later received an email from airline to bring the physical card at check-in

Tags: cancellations

The airline is Oman Air. I tried 3 times to buy the ticket with my Capital one 360 and it failed everytime. So I had to use privacy.com as a last resort. My flight is in two days and now I received an email that after reviewing the transaction they need me to bring the physical card. Has anyone experienced something like this before like using a virtual visa card and what happened. I am so worried because my flight is categorically non-refundable.